# Is there a way to modify json received callback?

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I'm receiving a callback from a server in my Google app script via doPost.
The problem is, my Json format is with a this word in front of the Json "Data=", because of that I'm not able to work with the Json callback.

The code:

```
Function doPost(e){
var r = e.postdata.contents
Logger.log(r)
}
I'm receiving the bellow format.

data={""retorno"":{""estoques"":[{""estoque"":{""codigo"":""001a"",""nome"":""M\u00e1scara 100% Algod\u00e3o Lav\u00e1vel Dupla Prote\u00e7\u00e3o - 10 Unidades"",""estoqueAtual"":50,""depositos"":[{""deposito"":{""id"":7939278964,""nome"":""Geral"",""saldo"":""50.0000000000"",""desconsiderar"":""N"",""saldoVirtual"":""50.0000000000""}}]}}]}}
```

Anyway to remove this "Data="?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the output of: Logger.log(typeof r) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you just want to remove the substring `data=` - the easiest would be to use the method [silce()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp)

Sample:

```
var r = e.postdata.contents;
var sliced = r.toString().slice(5);
Logger.log(slide);
```